# How to set Product lifetime for products in In-App Purchase on Windows Phone Beta application?

Tags: windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase, beta

I would like to use In-app purchase in a Windows Phone application. To check my work, I published a Beta application. Everything work except the products have expiration date of 31/12/9999.

On the Dev Center, I choosed Product Lifetime = 1 day. I tried to delete and create another product but I've still the same expiration date.

Is it because my application is a beta? Will it work when I will publish my app on the WP Store?

Thank you for the help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because it is a beta app. In app purchases in beta apps are not charged and don't expire. You can use a mock server to test your in app purchase handling.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681689(v=vs.105).aspx for more details on setting up a mocking service.